# Dell Latitude E6410 RAM upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, dell-latitude

I am upgrading my laptop's RAM. Currently it has Samsung RAM PC3. I inserted two different RAMs and they both hung the system. The new RAMs are PC3L.

I just read that this might be the problem. Can anyone tell me more about this? I have read that PC3 RAMs and PC3L RAMs are interchangeable, then why this problem?

MemTest x86 gave "Unexpected Interrupt" error in both the newer RAMs. The RAMs are not faulty, they were working in other systems.

**SPECS:**

- Dell Latitude E6410
- Intel Core i7 920M
- 4 GB RAM

  - 2 x 2GiB [Samsung M471B5673FH0-CF8](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/product/computing-dram/detail?productId=5882&iaId=694))
  - SODIMM (Small outline DIMM, aka laptop memory)
  - Memory type: DDR3
  - Sold as 1067 MHz (0.9 ns). (Runs at 533MHz)
  - Also branded as type PC3-8500
  - Runs at 1.5v and 1.35v
- New RAMs:

  - Samsung 4GB PC3L (4GiB [M471B5173BH0-YK0](http://www.electrobyt.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=6442))
  - SODIMM.
  - DDR3
  - Sold at 1600MHz (runs at 800MHz)
  - PC3-12800 (more bandwidth than PC3-8500)
  - Low Voltgage (1.35v)

Comment: Which specific RAM did it ship with? (2x2GB PC3 is not specific enough).  What kind of RAM are you trying to replace it with (again, just PC3L is not specific enough. Those just indicate that you are using the low voltage (L) version of one of many DDR3 SoDIMMs).

Comment: I have edited the RAM details. Please tell if there is something misssing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the E6410, Dell states that this laptop only supports 1333mhz max.  Your new memory is 1600mhz, even if you say it "runs at 800mhz".  There is no indication that this motherboard will work with low-voltage memory, either.   Why not buy memory that is intended to be compatible with your motherboard?

Comment: Can't even vote up. Well the stupid shop keeper said that it would work on my model. I'll get it changed. Thanks for the response. Will post the results.

Comment: @ZackValentine - don't worry about the upvote.  If this resolves the issue (as I expect) you can always award the answer.  I tend to be wary of just how much most retail folks really know about what works and what doesn't. I'd trust Crucial to tell me what memory is compatible, and of course Dell, but not the guys at Office Depot (unless they have a catalog or reference that I can double-check.)

Comment: Well we don't have such helpful people here, just random shop keepers. It was the bus thing. They don't have 1333MHz RAM available here. So I am stuck with my 4GB (2 x 2GB) RAM for now. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: You can take it a step down from there, to the the 1066, of course.  That may be easier to procure.  And yeah, the "it fits in the slot" folks can't be relied on for compatibility advice. I'm not sure why you were downvoted here unless it was when you lacked the necessary details in your post. The "takeaway" is that fitting in a slot is not enough, that most systems will accommodate a range of speeds but you can't guess where they top out (have to go to the mfr's info).

Answer (score 2):

E6410 uses 1st generation processors i3 or i5 or i7, they support between 800 to 1066 MHz,installing 1333 MHz may work and not work in certain scenarios, it is better to stick to 1066mhz. Although 1333 MHz scales down to 1066mhz, if not designed specifically for the E6410 it may not work. Some E6410 ships with pc10600 4 gb ram which is 1333 but they scale down as 1066 well, I tried a transcend  pc10600 1333mhz 8 gb which worked for 32 bit win 7 but did not allow 64 bit install, so I would say either go with a 1066 MHz ram for a 64 bit install or try to match a 1333 MHz ram specifically compatible with e6410.

As far as mixing PC3 RAMs and PC3L RAMs its a definite NO NO they both operate at different volt 1.5 and 1.3 although PC3L can work on both volts.

Comment: If PC3L can operate at both voltages then why can't you mix one PC3 and one PC3L chip?

Comment: I tried mixing PC3L and PC3 on my E6410 PC10600 RAM chips and it worked fine.